# How to use gazebo plugins found in gazebo_ros [ROS2 Foxy gazebo11]

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, gazebo-plugins, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the gazebo_ros_state plugin found inside the gazebo_ros folder in gazebo_ros_pkgs.

I have included this inside my world file similar to the demo also found in gazebo_ros folder...

```
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_state" filename="libgazebo_ros_state.so">
      <ros>
        <namespace>/demo</namespace>
        <argument>model_states:=model_states_demo</argument>
      </ros>
      <update_rate>1.0</update_rate>
  </plugin>
```

I also tried to see if the migration guide found here (https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-Entity-states and https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-gazebo_ros_api_plugin) gave any info on it however nothing there seemed to offer any help.

This is the error I am getting when I try and start my world...

[Err] [Model.cc:1097] Model[cartpole] is attempting to load a plugin, but detected an incorrect plugin type. Plugin filename[libgazebo_ros_state.so] name[gazebo_ros_state]

libgazebo_ros_state.so is found inside my lib folder just like my other plugins

One more thing to note is that I have other plugins found in the gazebo_plugin folder that work and do not give an error like this...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356936/how-to-use-gazebo-plugins-found-in-gazebo_ros-%5Bros2-foxy-gazebo11%5D/) by [Dawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/55621/dawson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-07-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BorgesJVT](https://answers.ros.org/users/55815/borgesjvt/) on 2020-09-15**:
I am having the same problem. Any updates here?

**Comment by [guru_florida](https://answers.ros.org/users/49713/guru_florida/) on 2020-09-27**:
I took the gazebo_ros_state_demo.world straight from the repo. Strangely, I get the same error but regardless it seems to work and I get the two service endpoints /demo/get_entity_state and /demo/set_entity_state and they do correctly return model data.

**Comment by [sherlockshome221](https://answers.ros.org/users/36871/sherlockshome221/) on 2021-06-24**:
I have one observation. The `gazebo_ros_state` plugin is registered as a WORLD_PLUGIN type [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/3f18465d3fac30c729f9406eff0fda67ab606502/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_state.cpp#L313). The error in the OP is coming from `model.cc` which is looking for `MODEL_PLUGIN` type [here](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/a708aa3008b1a27cb5adb65a6f21704ceb535b53/gazebo/physics/Model.cc#L1120).

So, it seems the problem here is, the addition of the plugin in the sdf file is not having the desired effect of specifying a WORLD_PLUGIN. I wonder if the `<plugin>` tag added in the OP is under the `<model>` or under `<world>`. Not sure if that's a fix to the problem. But sharing a thought as I am trying to fix the same too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following up on my comment above:
The `gazebo_ros_state` plugin is registered as a WORLD_PLUGIN type [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/3f18465d3fac30c729f9406eff0fda67ab606502/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_state.cpp#L313). The error in the OP is coming from `model.cc` which is looking for `MODEL_PLUGIN` type [here](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/a708aa3008b1a27cb5adb65a6f21704ceb535b53/gazebo/physics/Model.cc#L1120).

So, the problem here is, the addition of the plugin in the sdf file is not having the desired effect of specifying a WORLD_PLUGIN. Adding the `<plugin>` under the `<world>` tag directly like below works without issues:

```
<world name="default">
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_state" filename="libgazebo_ros_state.so">
          <ros>
            <namespace>/demo</namespace>
            <argument>model_states:=model_states_demo</argument>
          </ros>
          <update_rate>1.0</update_rate>
        </plugin>
</world>
```

Starting this world with `gazebo my_world_file.world --verbose` and then doing a `ros2 service list | grep entity` gives:

```
/demo/get_entity_state
/demo/set_entity_state
```

---

Originally posted by [sherlockshome221](https://answers.ros.org/users/36871/sherlockshome221/) with karma: 46 on 2021-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sherlockshome221](https://answers.ros.org/users/36871/sherlockshome221/) on 2021-06-24**:
Related answer [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/360161/ros2-dashing-service-get_entity_state-is-missing/)